# Use Credentials Provided to Sharepoint for Webservice Authentification

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, web-services

I created a webpart that is able to consume a service provided by Dynamics NAV 2009 R2. I documented in short what I did so far: http://shb.vps.bitfolk.com/nav-sharepoint.html

I use the following method to get a swsEmployeeCard-Object:

```
private swsEmployeeCard GetTestEmployeeCard()
{
    swsEmployeeCard_Service service = new swsEmployeeCard_Service();
    String companyName = "CRONUS-Schweiz-AG";
    service.Url = "http://localhost:7047/DynamicsNAV/WS/"
        +companyName
        +"/Page/swsEmployeeCard";
    service.Credentials =
        new System.Net.NetworkCredential("USER", "PASSWD", "DOMAIN");
    return service.Read("1000");
}
```

Now, it comes to where I get stuck. I have to pass credentials to the webservice (see service.Credentials = ... in code above). Needless to say that hard coded credentials are not very much what we want. So my question is: "How do I get User, Password and Domain from Sharepoint in which my webpart runs?"

I tried something like

```
private SPUser GetCurrentUser()
{
    SPWeb currentWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
    SPUser currentUser = currentWeb.CurrentUser;
    return currentUser;
}
```

but I could not figure out how to get the above mentioned parameters out of this SPUser object.

## Edit

I followed the link (configuring-kerberos-authentication-in-sharepoint) mentioned above. I changed code from

```
private swsEmployeeCard GetTestEmployeeCard()
{
    // snip
    service.Credentials =
        new System.Net.NetworkCredential("USER", "PASSWD", "DOMAIN");
    // snip
```

to

```
private swsEmployeeCard GetTestEmployeeCard()
{
    // snip
    service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    // snip
```

And I got an error in Sharepoint like

```
// snip
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException:
The login failed when connecting to SQL Server MYSERVER.
// snip
```

Obviously I am not using the proper way to pass credentials. What do I have to do, now I have Kerberos.

## Edit (David):

On further investigation, it seems that UseCurrentCredentials may be using `NT AUTHORITY\IUSR`, the IIS user. There is an additional configuration which we are missing here.

Additionally, the below does not work either:

```
//Create the Windows Identity for impersonation
    WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity = null;

    string upnFromClaim = null;
    foreach (Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.Claim claim in currentIdentity.Claims)
    {
        if (StringComparer.Ordinal.Equals(System.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimTypes.Upn, claim.ClaimType))
        {
            upnFromClaim = claim.Value;
            break;
        }
    }

    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(
        delegate
        {
            windowsIdentity = S4UClient.UpnLogon(upnFromClaim); //TODO Continue here

            //Check the C2WTS Windows Identity
            if (windowsIdentity != null)
            {
                //Make call as impsersonated user.
                using (WindowsImpersonationContext ctx = windowsIdentity.Impersonate())
                {
                    //Call service here
                }
            }
```

Comment: the last part "doesn't work" means wrong identity?

Comment: Exactly, the service gives an access denied error even though impersonation works

Answer (score 2):

The SPUser object doesn't carry password information. That is sent alongside whatever authentication you're using. If it's NTLM, unfortunately (for your purposes, anyway; there are very good reasons for this), you aren't going to be able to retrieve the password. This stems from a problem called the [Double Hop Issue](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2008/08/22/iis-windows-authentication-and-the-double-hop-issue.aspx).

One way, perhaps the easiest way to get around this if you're using NTLM-based authentication is to switch to Kerberos. It has a lot of steps, and sometimes if you skip one or two you get some weird results, but it's doable and it's still not rocket surgery:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2009/10/20/configuring-kerberos-authentication-in-sharepoint-2010-part-1.aspx

Beyond that, if you just need *any* credentials, you could always hardcode something, of course.

Comment: John, I tried what you recommended (see my answer below). Have you got any other hints? Cheers Sam

Comment: @user17714 The "answer" is now moved to be a part of your question.

Comment: Also, Kerberos is configured properly for the above.